# Using py2app to deploy an application using opencv for Mac

Tags: python, opencv, deployment, static-linking, py2app

I finished scripting a a computer vision algorithm in python that rely heavily on opencv. I want to be able to deploy a standalone application to work under Mac OS that you don't have to preinstall any dependencies for.

After hours of searching the web I found people voting for py2app, however not many details on how to include opencv libraries for building.

- If you successfully deploy a similar application, please tell me what did you do?

Comment: have a look at [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20242421/1463143) for possible issues and solutions while trying to release opencv related apps for mac os x.

Comment: In general I have been using `pyinstaller` and `appdmg`, though admittedly I have not finished getting the deployment working with opencv, but I have qt working which is a big framework in it's own right